# Scipy Sparse Matrix Loop Taking Forever - Need to make more efficient

Tags: python, scipy, runtime, sparse-matrix, memory-efficient

What is the most efficient way time & memory wise of writing this loop with sparse matrix (currently using csc_matrix)

```
for j in range(0, reducedsize):
    xs = sum(X[:, j])
    X[:, j] = X[:, j] / xs.data[0]
```

example:

reduced size (int) - 2500 
X (csc_matrix) - 908x2500

The loop does iterate but it takes a very long time compared to just using numpy.

Comment: Why are you iterating?  Can't you do the column sum, and divide?  I'm going to ask for a concrete example (small).  Try whole matrix solution (in numpy if necessary), and then report on problems, if any.  Iteration is on sparse it extra slow.

Comment: This is just a small example. I'm using sparse matrix because X can blow up to be quite large and will take up to ~200GB. I'm iterating through the sparse matrix because every column will be normalized by the sum of that column.

Comment: When I copy-n-paste your example I get a `NameError` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to do it without any memory overhead (in-place)

Always think on how the data is actually stored.
A small example on a [csc matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html).

```
shape=(5,5)
X=sparse.random(shape[0], shape[1], density=0.5, format='csc')
print(X.todense())

[[0.12146814 0.         0.         0.04075121 0.28749552]
 [0.         0.92208639 0.         0.44279661 0.        ]
 [0.63509196 0.42334964 0.         0.         0.99160443]
 [0.         0.         0.25941113 0.44669367 0.00389409]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.83226886]]

i=0 #first column
print(X.data[X.indptr[i]:X.indptr[i+1]])
[0.12146814 0.63509196]
```

**A Numpy solution**

So the only thing we want to do here is to modify the nonzero entries column by column in place. This can be easily done using a partly vectorized numpy solution. `data` is just the array which contains all non zero values, `indptr` stores the information where each column begins and ends.

```
def Numpy_csc_norm(data,indptr):
    for i in range(indptr.shape[0]-1):
        xs = np.sum(data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]])
        #Modify the view in place
        data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]/=xs
```

Regarding performance this in-place solution is already not too bad. If you want to improve the performance further you could use Cython/Numba/ or some other compiled code which can be wrapped up in Python more or less easily.

**A Numba solution**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def Numba_csc_norm(data,indptr):
    for i in nb.prange(indptr.shape[0]-1):
        acc=0
        for j in range(indptr[i],indptr[i+1]):
            acc+=data[j]
        for j in range(indptr[i],indptr[i+1]):
            data[j]/=acc
```

**Performance**

```
#Create a not to small example matrix
shape=(50_000,10_000)
X=sparse.random(shape[0], shape[1], density=0.001, format='csc')

#Not in-place from hpaulj
def hpaulj(X):
    acc=X.sum(axis=0)
    return X.multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(1./acc))

%timeit X2=hpaulj(X)
#6.54 ms ± 67.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#All 2 variants are in-place, 
#but this shouldn't have a influence on the timings

%timeit Numpy_csc_norm(X.data,X.indptr)
#79.2 ms ± 914 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#parallel=False -> faster on tiny matrices
%timeit Numba_csc_norm(X.data,X.indptr)
#626 µs ± 30.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#parallel=True -> faster on larger matrices
%timeit Numba_csc_norm(X.data,X.indptr)
#185 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [388]: from scipy import sparse
```

Make a sample matrix:

```
In [390]: M = sparse.random(10,8,.2, 'csc')
```

Matrix sum:

```
In [393]: M.sum(axis=0)                                                                 
Out[393]: 
matrix([[1.95018736, 0.90924629, 1.93427113, 2.38816133, 1.08713479,
         0.        , 2.45435481, 0.        ]])
```

those 0's produce warning when dividing - and `nan` in the results:

```
In [394]: M/_                                                                           
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py:599: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  return np.true_divide(self.todense(), other)
Out[394]: 
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.27079623,
                nan, 0.13752665,        nan],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                nan, 0.32825122,        nan],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                nan, 0.        ,        nan],
 ...
                nan, 0.        ,        nan]])
```

the 0s also give a problem with your approach:

```
In [395]: for i in range(8): 
     ...:     xs = sum(M[:,i]) 
     ...:     M[:,i] = M[:,i]/xs.data[0] 
     ...:                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-395-0195298ead19> in <module>
      1 for i in range(8):
      2     xs = sum(M[:,i])
----> 3     M[:,i] = M[:,i]/xs.data[0]
      4 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

But if we compare the columns without 0 sum the values match:

```
In [401]: Out[394][:,:5]                                                                
Out[401]: 
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.27079623],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.49648886, 0.25626608, 0.        , 0.19162678, 0.72920377],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.30200765, 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.50351114, 0.        , 0.30445113, 0.41129367, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.74373392, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.39354122, 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.39707955, 0.        ]])
In [402]: M.A[:,:5]                                                                     
Out[402]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.27079623],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.49648886, 0.25626608, 0.        , 0.19162678, 0.72920377],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.30200765, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.50351114, 0.        , 0.30445113, 0.41129367, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.74373392, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.39354122, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.39707955, 0.        ]])
```

Back in [394] I should have first converted the matrix sum to sparse, so the result will also be sparse.  Sparse doesn't have elementwise divide, so I had to take the dense matrix inverse first.  The 0s are still a nuisance.

```
In [409]: M.multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(1/Out[393]))                                     
...
Out[409]: 
<10x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 16 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```